# A designation for a person who simplifies things for others

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pronouns

I am looking out for a formal word to be used as a designation for a person who simplifies things at work by automating everything.

Comment: Business Analyst or Efficiency Expert.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the word *automator*; just like *mediator* can be used for somebody who is occupied with *mediation*, an *automator* is occupied with *automation*. Note that (thanks @AndrewLeach) some words ending in *-tion* (like 'promotion') use *-ter* instead.

*Automator* is also the name of a [macOS component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_macOS_components#Automator) which you can use to automate certain tasks on your computer.

Comment: Note that *promoter* is an *-er* word, not *-or*.